# Arithmetic /geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a sequence $2, x , y , 9$ where the first three terms form an arithmetic progression and the last three terms form a geometric progression, determine the value(s) of $x$ and $y$. Need assistance with this question please.

Comment: What work have you done so far/ where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I've done the common difference and common ratio equaling both equations to each other. T2/T1=T2/T1 but I don't know what to do next

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

- In an arithmetic sequence $\dots,a-d,a,a+d,\dots$, one has $(a-d)+(a+d) = 2a$.  In words, sum of surrounding terms is two times the sum of surrounded term.
- In a geometric sequence $\dots,ar^{-1},a,ar\dots$, one has $ar^{-1} \cdot ar = a^2$.

> \begin{cases} 2+y&=2x & \text{(arithmetic progression)} \\ 9x&=y^2 & \text{(geometric progression)}  \end{cases}

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Can you specify which part you don't understand?  Say, the 1st point?

Comment: The two equations in the spoiler

Comment: @Jess I added four words into the spoiler.  Please reply if you can't get it.

Comment: Thanks that makes more sense!

Answer (score 0):

For A.P.
$T_1=a=2.............$
$T_2=a+(2-1)d$
     $=2+d.$    equation(**$1$**)..............
$T_3=a+(3-1)d$
    $=2+2d.$  equation ($2$).............

For G.P.
$x/y=y/9$........
$ y2= 9x$........
$4+8d+4d×d =9(2+d)$.  .......

$4d×d-d-14=0$........
$d=-7/4$.......
Or...
$d=2$......
.
Put in equation $1$ and $2$......

And you get ......
$x=4$ and $y=6$.....
And.....
$x=1/$4   and $y=-3/2$.....

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.
For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Sry i am new on this next time I will do

Comment: What do all these dots mean..............?

Comment: I suppose they are horizontal spaces

Comment: When I submit my ans  all equations are in straight line

Comment: So I separated by dots

Answer (score 0):

First from the arithmetic progression we have $x-2=y-x$ which gives us $y=2x-2$. Second from the geometric progression we have $\frac{y}{x}=\frac{9}{y}$. We plug in $y=2x-2$ into this equation and get $$\frac{2x-2}{x}=\frac{9}{2x-2}.$$ Can you solve this to find $x$ and hence $y$?